# Pandas create column from row entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I would like to group the url and create new columns for word where url is the same.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url':['/pool','/refrigerators','/refrigerators','/refrigerators','/joss-and-main','/furniture','/entertainment-centers-and-tv-stands'], 
'word':['pool','refrigerator','fridge','cooler','joss and main','furniture','tv stand']})
```

Wanted Output:

```
Url word    word1   word2
/pool   pool        
/refrigerators  refrigerator    fridge  cooler
/joss-and-main  joss and main       
/furniture  furniture       
/entertainment-centers-and-tv-stands    tv stand
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way using `groupby`.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url':['/pool','/refrigerators','/refrigerators','/refrigerators','/joss-and-main','/furniture','/entertainment-centers-and-tv-stands'], 
                    'word':['pool','refrigerator','fridge','cooler','joss and main','furniture','tv stand']})

# groupby to list
s = df2.groupby('url')['word'].apply(list)
lst = s.values.tolist()

# pad inner lists so they have same length
maxlen = max(map(len, lst))
lst = [i+['']*(maxlen-len(i)) for i in lst]

# build split dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['word'+str(i) for i in range(1,maxlen+1)], index=s.index)\
        .reset_index()

#                                     url          word1   word2   word3
# 0  /entertainment-centers-and-tv-stands       tv stand                
# 1                            /furniture      furniture                
# 2                        /joss-and-main  joss and main                
# 3                                 /pool           pool                
# 4                        /refrigerators   refrigerator  fridge  cooler
```

Comment: I would have never thought of this solution, thank you